# Optimising a complex view that uses several CTE's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, common-table-expression

I am looking for some guidance on any glaring errors I am making in regards to performance for this view, as it currently taking over 1m 46s just to query the view and over 3m if I add a WHERE clause against the period and year.

The purpose of the view is to collate financial information for several weeks and group that information by period and year. This view is then referenced throughout the financial system for reporting and generating orders into other financial systems.

The query was too long for me to post on here so I have provided a link to the query and I can provide any information about tables upon request:
https://pastebin.com/x8dV8KLJ

Below is just the common table expressions for the query as StackOverflow insisted I post some code to accompany the link:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[UnitFinancialFigures] AS

WITH
ctePeriodWeekCount AS (
    SELECT Count(Week.WeekNo) AS WeekCount, PrdNo AS Period, PrdYear AS Year
    FROM Week
    INNER JOIN Period on Week.WeekEndDate BETWEEN Period.StartDate AND Period.EndDate
    GROUP BY PrdNo, PrdYear),

cteLabourFigures AS (
    SELECT Labour.LabUnitId, Labour.LabPeriod, Labour.LabYear,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LabourTypes.LTypeIsPayrollLabour = 1 THEN LabourBreakdown.LBrkAmount ELSE 0 END) AS PayRollLabour,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LabourTypes.LTypeIsPayrollLabour = 0 THEN LabourBreakdown.LBrkAmount ELSE 0 END) AS OtherLabour
    FROM Labour
    INNER JOIN LabourBreakdown on LabourBreakDown.LBrkLabId = Labour.LabId
    INNER JOIN LabourTypes on LabourTypes.LTypeId = LabourBreakdown.LBrkLTypeId
    GROUP BY Labour.LabUnitId, Labour.LabPeriod, Labour.LabYear),

cteMobileRelief AS (
    SELECT McDtUnitId, McHdPeriod, McHdYear, SUM(McDtAmount) AS MobileReliefTotal
    FROM MobileCostHeader
    INNER JOIN MobileCostDetail on MobileCostDetail.McDtHdId = MobileCostHeader.MCHdId
    GROUP BY McDtUnitId, McHdPeriod, McHdYear),

cteInvoices AS (
    SELECT Period.PrdNo, Period.PrdYear, Invoice.AccountID, SUM(Invoice.InvTotalInclVat) AS TotalInvoices,
    SUM(Invoice.InvVatAmount) AS TotalInvoicesVat
    FROM [SOP].Invoice
    INNER JOIN Period on Invoice.InvoiceDate BETWEEN Period.StartDate AND Period.EndDate
    GROUP By Period.PrdNo, Period.PrdYear, Invoice.AccountID),

cteSundryCosts AS (
    SELECT ScDtAccountId, ScDtPeriodNo, ScDtYearNo, SUM(ScdtTotal) AS SundryTotal,
    SUM(ScdtAmount) AS SundryNetTotal,
    SUM(ScdtVatAmount) AS SundryVatAmount
    FROM SundryCostDetail
    WHERE ScdtRepeat = 0
    GROUP BY ScDtAccountId, ScDtPeriodNo, ScDtYearNo),

cteAdditionalProfit AS (
    SELECT ScDtAccountId, ScDtPeriodNo, ScDtYearNo, SUM(ScdtTotal) AS AdditionalProfitTotal,
    SUM(ScdtAmount) AS AdditionalProfitNetTotal,
    SUM(ScdtVatAmount) AS AdditionalProfitVatAmount
    FROM SundryCostDetail
    WHERE ScdtRepeat = 0 AND SCdtExcludeFromGP = 0
    GROUP BY ScDtAccountId, ScDtPeriodNo, ScDtYearNo),

cteCashReceived AS (
    SELECT CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear,
    SUM(CtAmount - CtAgentVatAmount) AS GoodsAmount, SUM(CtVatAmount + CtAgentVatAmount) AS VatTotal, SUM(CtTotal) AS Total,
    SUM(VATFree.CanaAmount - VATFree.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS VATFreeGoodsAmount,
    SUM(Catering.CanaAmount - Catering.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS CateringGoodsAmount,
    SUM(Vending.CanaAmount - Vending.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS VendingGoodsAmount,
    SUM(CansConf.CanaAmount - CansConf.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS CansConfGoodsAmount
    FROM CashTran
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS VATFree ON CashTran.CtId = VATFree.CanaTranId AND VATFree.CanaCode = 'G201'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS Catering ON CashTran.CtId = Catering.CanaTranId AND Catering.CanaCode = 'G205'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS Vending ON CashTran.CtId = Vending.CanaTranId AND Vending.CanaCode = 'G202'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS CansConf ON CashTran.CtId = CansConf.CanaTranId AND CansConf.CanaCode = 'G203'
    WHERE CtCategoryId = 3 AND CtApproved = 1 ANd CtTranType = 'R'
    GROUP BY CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear),

cteFreeIssues AS (
    SELECT CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear,
    SUM(CtAmount - CtAgentVatAmount) AS GoodsAmount, SUM(CtVatAmount + CtAgentVatAmount) AS VatTotal, SUM(CtTotal) AS Total,
    SUM(Catering.CanaAmount - Catering.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS CateringGoodsAmount,
    SUM(Vending.CanaAmount - Vending.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS VendingGoodsAmount,
    SUM(CansConf.CanaAmount - CansConf.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS CansConfGoodsAmount,
    SUM(Labour.CanaAmount - Labour.CanaAgentVatAmount) AS LabourGoodsAmount
    FROM CashTran
    INNER JOIN [SOP].Accounts ON Accounts.AcUniqueId = CtUnitId
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS Catering ON CashTran.CtId = Catering.CanaTranId AND Catering.CanaCode = 'G204'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS Vending ON CashTran.CtId = Vending.CanaTranId AND Vending.CanaCode = 'G202'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS CansConf ON CashTran.CtId = CansConf.CanaTranId AND CansConf.CanaCode = 'G203'
    LEFT JOIN CashAnalysis AS Labour ON CashTran.CtId = Labour.CanaTranId AND Labour.CanaCode = 'H995'
    WHERE CtCategoryId = 2
    GROUP BY CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear),

cteExternalFreeIssues AS (
    SELECT CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear, SUM(CtAmount - CtAgentVatAmount) AS GoodsAmount, SUM(CtVatAmount + CtAgentVatAmount) AS VatTotal, SUM(CtTotal) AS Total
    FROM CashTran
    INNER JOIN [SOP].Accounts on Accounts.AcUniqueId = CtUnitId
    WHERE CtCategoryId = 4
    GROUP BY CtUnitId, CtPeriod, CtYear),

cteAgencyLabour AS (
    SELECT PtUnitId, PtYear, PtPeriod, SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PanaGoodsAmount - PanaAgentVatAmount ELSE -(PanaGoodsAmount - PanaAgentVatAmount) END) Total
    FROM PurchaseTran
    INNER Join PurchaseAnalysis on PurchaseAnalysis.PanaTranId = PurchaseTran.PtId
    INNER JOIN [SOP].Accounts on Accounts.AcUniqueID = PtUnitId
    INNER JOIN UnitAnalysisConfig on UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgAnalysisCode = PurchaseAnalysis.PanaPCode AND UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgType = 1
    WHERE PurchaseAnalysis.PanaPCode = 'H995' AND (PtTranType = 'I' Or PtTranType = 'C') AND PtApproved =1
    GROUP BY PtUnitId, PtPeriod, PtYear),

ctePurchases AS (
    SELECT PurchaseTran.PtUnitId, PurchaseTran.PtPeriod, PurchaseTran.PtYear,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PtTotal WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN - PtTotal ELSE 0 END) AS PurchaseTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PtAmount - PtAgentVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(PtAmount - PtAgentVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS PurchaseNetTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PtVat + PtAgentVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(PtVat + PtAgentVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS VatTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtSupplierId = CmpCashAccount THEN PtTotal ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCashPaid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN Catering.PanaGoodsAmount - Catering.PanaAgentVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(Catering.PanaGoodsAmount - Catering.PanaAgentVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) CateringTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN Catering.PanaAgentVatAmount + Catering.PanaVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(Catering.PanaAgentVatAmount + Catering.PanaVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS CateringVatAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN Vending.PanaGoodsAmount - Vending.PanaAgentVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(Vending.PanaGoodsAmount - Vending.PanaAgentVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) VendingTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN Vending.PanaAgentVatAmount + Vending.PanaVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(Vending.PanaAgentVatAmount + Vending.PanaVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS VendingVatAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN CansConf.PanaGoodsAmount - CansConf.PanaAgentVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(CansConf.PanaGoodsAmount - CansConf.PanaAgentVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) CansConfTotal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN CansConf.PanaAgentVatAmount + CansConf.PanaVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(CansConf.PanaAgentVatAmount + CansConf.PanaVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS CansConfVatAmount
    FROM PurchaseTran
    INNER JOIN CompParam on Compparam.CmpDefault = 1
    INNER JOIN [SOP].Accounts on Accounts.AcUniqueID = PurchaseTran.PtUnitId
    LEFT JOIN PurchaseAnalysis AS Catering on Catering.PanaTranId = PurchaseTran.PtId AND (Catering.PanaPCode = 'H201' OR Catering.PanaPCode = 'H401')
    LEFT JOIN PurchaseAnalysis AS Vending on Vending.PanaTranId = PurchaseTran.PtId AND Vending.PanaPCode = 'H202'
    LEFT JOIN PurchaseAnalysis AS CansConf on CansConf.PanaTranId = PurchaseTran.PtId AND CansConf.PanaPCode = 'H211'
    WHERE (PtTranType = 'I' OR PtTranType = 'C') AND PtApproved = 1
    GROUP BY PtUnitId, PtPeriod, PtYear),

cteSundryPurchases AS (
    SELECT PtUnitId, PtYear, PtPeriod,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PanaGoodsAmount - PanaAgentVatAmount ELSE -(PanaGoodsAmount - PanaAgentVatAmount) END) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PtTranType = 'I' THEN PanaAgentVatAmount + PanaVatAmount WHEN PtTranType = 'C' THEN -(PanaAgentVatAmount + PanaVatAmount) ELSE 0 END) AS VatAmount
    FROM PurchaseTran
    INNER Join PurchaseAnalysis on PurchaseAnalysis.PanaTranId = PurchaseTran.PtId
    INNER JOIN [SOP].Accounts on Accounts.AcUniqueID = PurchaseTran.PtUnitId
    INNER JOIN UnitAnalysisConfig on UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgAnalysisCode = PurchaseAnalysis.PanaPCode AND (UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgType = 1 OR UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgType = 3)
    WHere UnitAnalysisConfig.UACfgTandOLabel = 'Sundry' AND (PtTranType = 'I' Or PtTranType = 'C') AND PtApproved = 1
    GROUP BY PtUnitId, PtPeriod, PtYear),

cteDiscount AS (
    SELECT PurchaseTran.PtUnitId, SUM(CASE WHEN PtTRanType = 'I' THEN PtDiscountAmount ELSE -PtDiscountAmount END) AS DiscountTotal, PtPeriod, PtYear
    FROM PurchaseTran
    WHERE PurchaseTran.PtApproved = 1 And (PurchaseTran.PtTranType = 'I' OR PurchaseTran.PtTranType = 'C')
    GROUP BY PurchaseTran.PtUnitId, PtPeriod, PtYear),

cteUnitPeriodOpeningStock AS (
    SELECT UStkId, UStkOpening, UnitStock.UStkUnitId, UnitStock.UStkPeriod, UnitStock.UStkYearNo, SUM(OpeningCatering.USAnaAmount) AS OpeningCateringStock, SUM(OpeningBeverage.USAnaAmount) AS OpeningBeverageStock, SUM(OpeningSundry.USAnaAmount) AS OpeningSundryStock, SUM(OpeningCansConf.USAnaAmount) AS OpeningCansConfStock
    FROM UnitStock
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS OpeningCatering ON UnitStock.UStkId = OpeningCatering.USAnaTranId AND OpeningCatering.USanaType = 'O' AND OpeningCatering.USAnaCode = 'CAT001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS OpeningBeverage ON UnitStock.UStkId = OpeningBeverage.USAnaTranId AND OpeningBeverage.USanaType = 'O' AND OpeningBeverage.USAnaCode = 'BEV001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS OpeningSundry ON UnitStock.UStkId = OpeningSundry.USAnaTranId AND OpeningSundry.USanaType = 'O' AND OpeningSundry.USAnaCode = 'SUN001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS OpeningCansConf ON UnitStock.UStkId = OpeningCansConf.USAnaTranId AND OpeningCansConf.USanaType = 'O' AND OpeningCansConf.USAnaCode = 'CAN001'
    INNER JOIN Week on Week.WeekNo = UnitStock.UStkWeeKNo AND Week.WeekYear = UnitStock.UStkYearNo
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT UStkUnitId, UStkPeriod, MIN(Week.WeekEndDate) OpeningDate
        FROM UnitStock
        INNER JOIN Week on Week.WeekNo = UnitStock.UStkWeeKNo AND Week.WeekYear = UnitStock.UStkYearNo
        GROUP BY UStkUnitId, UStkPeriod) OpeningData on OpeningData.OpeningDate = Week.WeekEndDate AND OpeningData.UStkUnitId = UnitStock.UStkUnitId
    GROUP BY UStkId, UStkOpening, UnitStock.UStkUnitId, UnitStock.UStkPeriod, UnitStock.UStkYearNo),

cteUnitPeriodClosingStock AS (
    SELECT UStkId, UStkClosing, UnitStock.UStkUnitId, UnitStock.UStkPeriod, UnitStock.UStkYearNo, SUM(ClosingCatering.USAnaAmount) AS ClosingCateringStock, SUM(ClosingBeverage.USAnaAmount) AS ClosingBeverageStock, SUM(ClosingSundry.USAnaAmount) AS ClosingSundryStock, SUM(ClosingCansConf.USAnaAmount) AS ClosingCansConfStock
    FROM UnitStock
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS ClosingCatering ON UnitStock.UStkId = ClosingCatering.USAnaTranId AND ClosingCatering.USanaType = 'C' AND ClosingCatering.USAnaCode = 'CAT001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS ClosingBeverage ON UnitStock.UStkId = ClosingBeverage.USAnaTranId AND ClosingBeverage.USanaType = 'C' AND ClosingBeverage.USAnaCode = 'BEV001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS ClosingSundry ON UnitStock.UStkId = ClosingSundry.USAnaTranId AND ClosingSundry.USanaType = 'C' AND ClosingSundry.USAnaCode = 'SUN001'
    LEFT JOIN UnitStockAnalysis AS ClosingCansConf ON UnitStock.UStkId = ClosingCansConf.USAnaTranId AND ClosingCansConf.USanaType = 'C' AND ClosingCansConf.USAnaCode = 'CAN001'
    INNER JOIN Week on Week.WeekNo = UnitStock.UStkWeeKNo AND Week.WeekYear = UnitStock.UStkYearNo
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT UStkUnitId, UStkPeriod, MAX(Week.WeekEndDate) ClosingDate
        FROM UnitStock
        INNER JOIN Week on Week.WeekNo = UnitStock.UStkWeeKNo AND Week.WeekYear = UnitStock.UStkYearNo
        GROUP BY UStkUnitId, UStkPeriod) ClosingData on ClosingData.ClosingDate = Week.WeekEndDate AND ClosingData.UStkUnitId = UnitStock.UStkUnitId
    GROUP BY UStkId, UStkClosing, UnitStock.UStkUnitId, UnitStock.UStkPeriod, UnitStock.UStkYearNo)
```

**EDIT After responses**
Thank you for the feedback. I followed the suggestions and worked on optimising each CTE query individually. My mistake was in expecting the execution plan to tell me if there were suggested indexes missing when I ran the view; it wasn't until I broke up the queries that I actually got any suggestions. It's also helpful to know I wasn't doing anything obvious that was clearly hurting the performance. After adding various indexes I got the view to around 30s.

Comment: Your query looks too large to likely get an answer here, but as a general comment I will say that a (non materialized) view only performs as well as the underlying queries.  So, if you want to speed up your view, you will need to tune the underlying queries.

Comment: Considered indexed view (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) ?

Comment: A lot of your CTEs look superfluous, in that they're querying the same base tables with slightly different conditions. The optimizer will try to query this as smart as possible, but it's not going to proactively merge queries with different conditions. Consider if it's possible to stick some of those conditions in columns (`CASE`) and then query or group by them later.

Comment: Alternatively, the sheer number of tables and joins and conditions you've got here suggest that there's actually another database struggling to get out of this one, or at least a different form of indexing. Consider (new or existing) tables with columnstore indexes or an Analysis Services database or possibly even a separately maintained warehouse database to compute and store these derived tables in advance. While that's redundant, it's the useful kind of redundancy (where the result is never modified independently) as opposed to the evil kind.

Comment: Could you add the final `SELECT` please, it would the base for any improvement suggestions

Comment: There is another participant who does not like _long reads_ as well - sql server's query optimizer. When a statement is that big (and this entire `view` is a single statement) it may fail finding the very optimum way to perform it. This one looks like a big report which perhaps would work better as a big SP with several @ or #. An SP with _small statements_ which can easily be analyzed by sql server's optimizer, understood, debugged and refactored by developers. Which again leads to the first comment by Tim about "underlying queries".

Comment: This view has the smell of using nested views also which is a sure way to decimate performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment by Tim, a (non materialized) view only performs as well as the underlying queries. So first analyse queries for optimization like adding non-clustered indexes on highly used columns (in joins or as foreign keys).

Apart from that you can also look into **[Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017)** for further increase in performance. But there are some catches for Indexes Views too as they are not also fool proof way to increase view performance like:

1. When executing DML on a table referenced by a large number of indexed views, or fewer but very complex indexed views, those referenced indexed views will have to be updated as well. As a result, DML query performance can degrade significantly, or in some cases, a query plan cannot even be produced.
   In such scenarios, test your DML queries before production use, analyze the query plan and tune/simplify the DML statement, such as UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT operations.
2. The cost of an indexed view is on the maintenance of the clustered index (and any non-clustered indexes you may choose to add). One must weigh the cost to maintain the index against the benefit of query optimization provided by the index.

For more information refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer

Answer (score 0):

If all your CTE queries perform at acceptable level but the entire statement does not (common) then you should convert CTE to temps like this:

```
--WITH
--ctePeriodWeekCount AS (...

--becomes

SELECT Count(Week.WeekNo) AS WeekCount, PrdNo AS Period, PrdYear AS Year
INTO #ctePeriodWeekCount FROM Week
INNER JOIN Period on Week.WeekEndDate BETWEEN Period.StartDate AND Period.EndDate
GROUP BY PrdNo, PrdYear
```

Then follow the CTE order by creating and use the appropriate temp table (just add a # in front of the name). Do not forget to drop temps at their last usage to release resources ASAP. Finally, if a filter is used at the end make sure you use it at temp creation SELECT statement.

Even if the final CTE performs close to individual ones it is good for performance to use temps - when future changes occur it is less likely to deal with performance problems.